# Check all checkboxes in p:selectCheckboxMenu

Tags: javascript, primefaces

How do I check every checkbox in `<p:selectCheckboxMenu>` after it is updated by a parent component. Could it be a JS/jQuery function or any other possibility.

I am trying to handle it with a javascript function to check every checkbox, called inside the `<p:ajax>` `oncomplete`

```
<p:selectOneMenu>
    <p:ajax update="selectCheckboxMenu" 
            oncomplete="checkEveryBoxes()"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:selectCheckboxMenu id="selectCheckboxMenu" widgetVar="wvCheckBoxMenu">
</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

JS(pseudocode):

```
function checkEveryBoxes(){
   for i=0 to y{
       check PF('wvCheckBoxMenu') for i value
   }
}
```

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`PrimeFaces.widget.SelectCheckboxMenu.checkAll()`](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/ccbb2f3c210d1c2e72af4c0668327bb2710a3a8d/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/forms/forms.js#L2319) function:

```
PF('wvCheckBoxMenu').checkAll()
```

Apparently after testing the function provided by PrimeFaces, the scenario of checking the checkboxes while the panel is closed is not present (a filter of `:visible`) thus if the menu is closed you won't get the expected result, so you need to call `show()` before calling `checkAll()`.

So the appropriate and the easiest sequence of calling would be:

```
PF('wvCheckBoxMenu').show();
PF('wvCheckBoxMenu').checkAll();
PF('wvCheckBoxMenu').hide()
```

Otherwise you need to alter the `checkAll()` function itself.

Comment: Nice! I made a JS function which works fines too, but your solution is way better! Thank you

Comment: btw, thank you for posting that reference page, it's very useful!

Comment: You're welcome. This is the github unofficial repository of PrimeFaces, it's good practice to read the code to come up with the best solution.